# create an interactive IntSlider widget

Tags: python, widget, bokeh, python-interactive

I am trying to create an interactive IntSlider widget, which calls another function when it updates. The function is callback(parameter) - the parameter inside is a rating.

The callback(rating) function's purpose is that it updates the visible businesses on the map according to their RatingValue.

So far my code looks like this:

```
def set_interactive():    
# YOUR CODE HERE

def f(x):
    return x = callback(RatingValue)

return interact(f, x=widgets.IntSlider(min=0,max=5,step=1,value=0));
```

When running this code, I get this error: 
return x = callback('RatingValue')
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Sometimes I also get this error: 
AttributeError: module 'bokeh.models.widgets' has no attribute 'IntSlider'

even though I have imported the IntSlider from the ipywidgets module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing up two different libraries. Bokeh widgets and ipywidgets are different things, In your code above, `widgets` is evidently the `bokeh.widgets` module (which does not have an `IntSlider` as the exception states). If there is an `IntSlider` in ipywidgets that you have imported, presumably you need to pass that:

```
return interact(f, x=IntSlider(min=0,max=5,step=1,value=0))  # no "widgets."
```